# LINQ Select all and get first five in skip take

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Hi i need suggestion to do this in linq. need to select all rows which are IsAvail = true and get 5 first rows. i done the following query

```
from i in entity.Bills.OrderBy(e => e.From).Skip(CurrentPage).Take(intRecordsPerPage)
join c in entity.Cust on i.Id equals c.Id into c_join
from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where i.IsAvail == true
select new { i, Id = c.Id };
```

But when the IsAvail is true in 6th recored i cant get it in first page. 
i can get in second page only, first page remains blank.
how can i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the Skip/Take at the *end* of the query:

```
var allRecords = from i in entity.Bills
                 where i.IsAvail
                 orderby i.From
                 join c in entity.Cust on i.Id equals c.Id into c_join
                 from c in c_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { i, Id = c.Id };

var page = allRecords.Skip(CurrentPage).Take(intRecordsPerPage);
```

(I've also put the `where` clause earlier and used query expressions for the whole thing, just for tidiness.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, it requires the Orderby before using skip take, i just edited it

Comment: @de_spen: The `OrderBy` is still before `Skip`/`Take`.